# how to reload directive data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am using this directives https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/XArO6p in my app. I want to refresh the data in this directive whenever the user revisits the the same page in my app. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be implemented as a component.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

using a controller with a constructor, you can invoke any initialization you need for the data.

Comment: but here if you see link function is used for DOM manipulation and according to 
 angular component it does not provide link function. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572648/8645679.